# Faking a toggle switch with an Input Range, dealing with custom range

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, range, toggle

I need to fake a toggle switch with an input range.
The idea is to create a short range, with just 2 values, min and max. the css button will match one end of the range. So far you click on it, the div containing the range will move a bit bringing the other end of the ranger under your mouse.

I have this function, which applies on all input ranges on the page. But i need to apply it only on some classes, not all. But i can't find the right syntax and it doesn't work.

The Javascript:

```
$('input[type="range"]').on('change', function() {
$('div#launcher01').css('margin-top', parseInt($(this).val()  ) > 0 ? parseInt($(this).val()  ) + 'px' : '0px');
    });
```

CSS:

```
.fakbl input {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
```

HTML:

```
<div id="launcher01">
<div class="fakbl">
<input type="range" id="launch01" name="launch01" min="0" max="50" step="50"" />
</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnhope/y1mewq8g/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using jQuery, you can phrase your widget-maker as a jQuery plugin as follows :

```
$.fn.rangeButton = function(containerSelector) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        $self.on('change', function() {
            $self.closest(containerSelector).css('margin-left', ($self.val()/3) > 0 ? ($self.val()/3) + 'px' : '0px');
        }).trigger('change'); // trigger 'change' immediately to initialize everything.
    });
};
```

Now, invoke the widget on each of your ranges, and pass a selector for the appropriate container :

```
$('#launcher01 input[type="range"]').rangeButton('#launcher01');
$('#launcher02 input[type="range"]').rangeButton('#launcher02');
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o1yhk24z/)**

Alternatively, by giving all containers the same class, you can invoke all your widgets with a single command :

```
$('.myClass input[type="range"]').rangeButton('.myClass');
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o1yhk24z/1/)**

Comment: Wow that's amazing Roamer! Thank you very much i really appreciate, i spent so many hours trying, and you made it so straight.

Comment: No worries. It gets easier with practice (and great age).

Answer (score 0):

May I ask a refinement please?

I completed the fake button. As you can see in this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/johnhope/2j8bx4s3/4/)

(the white box will disappear, I added some opacity to it just to show that the button is working)
The red box (now green due to my buggy code part) is in the background and I would need it to change color depending on the status. I tried this but it doesn't work. 
Here the code:

```
 $.fn.rangeButton = function(containerSelector) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $self = $(this);
            $self.on('change', function() {  
                $self.closest(containerSelector).css('margin-left',     ($self.val()/3) > 0 ? ($self.val()/3) + 'px' : '0px');


   //   this part is not working, if you remove this part, the button works flawlessy
          if ($self = 100) {
              document.getElementById("fakbuttonsfondo01").style.backgroundColor="rgb(0, 191, 1)"; 
          } else {
              document.getElementById("fakbuttonsfondo01").style.backgroundColor="rgb(0, 0, 255)"; 
          }  
    //   end of buggy code



            }).trigger('change'); // trigger 'change' immediately to initialize everything.
        });
    };

    $('#launcher01 input[type="range"]').rangeButton('#launcher01');
    $('#launcher02 input[type="range"]').rangeButton('#launcher02');
```

Thanks:)